# Convert given time into millisecond

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to convert given time into Milliseconds. My time format is 10:25:10 PM.

Comment: This question is easily researched on google: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

Comment: If you are doing many things related to time and date in Javascript, you may find https://momentjs.com/ to be very useful.

Comment: recommended reading `new Date().getTime();`

Comment: @EricB - he seems to want to convert only time into milliseconds (not date)

Comment: Flagged as **too-broad**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a free-code writing service. Before asking, you should do some research on it.

Comment: I want to convert only time....not date

Comment: Please see [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and use the [getMilliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds) function of that object.

**Example:**

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(22); //10 PM
d.setMinutes(25);
d.setSeconds(10);

console.log(d.getMilliseconds() + ' milliseconds');
```

Comment: Thanks @lealceldeiro